# Api payment gateway integration PHP

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway

My boss received a payment API ( it allows customer to pay in many instalments ) and asked me to integrate it to my website

But I'm a developper beginner and I don't really know where to start.

If I understood correctly, I need to get access token first.

- The Authorization type is : OAuth 2.0
- Header Prefix : Bearer
- Grant Type : Client Credientials
- Scope : Resource.WRITE, resource.READ
- Authorization data to : Request Header

How can I get the access token and refresh it ?

I tried something like this : ( but it isn't working )

```
<?php

$clientId = 'myclientid';
$clientSecret = 'myclientsecret';

function getToken(){
    $curl = curl_init();

    $params = [
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://test.auth.alphacredit.be/api/oauth/token',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,

        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(

            "content-type: application/json",
            "accept: */*",
            "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
            'Authorization: Bearer',
            


        ),
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'scope' => 'read, write',))
    ];

    curl_setopt_array($curl, $params);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Comment: Can you list documentation link for the above API integration?

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you need ? because that's almost all info they gave me. I'm new on stackoverflow, I don't really know how I can upload files when I'm replying to you

Comment: If you are new to programming, it is important to know that “not working” is not helpful. You have a desired outcome, you have some code, and you have a result, which might be an error.